# Menu Tabs do not function correctly in only Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8

Menu Tabs do not function correctly in only Internet Explorer 8Menu Tabs do not function correctly in only Internet Explorer 8The tab in the link Above on my HTML webpage do not work in IE8. They do work in IE9, safari, Firefox, opera ect.

The problem in IE is that when a tab is clicked it does not open.

HTML:

```
div id="tab2" class="css-tabs">
        <ul class="noint11_menu">
            <li id="item-1"> <a href="#item-1">Shipping</a>
                <div>
                    <p><img id="shippingtable" src="http://www.ubreakirepair.com/ebaysite/images/shippingtable.png"/></p>
                    <div class="footer">----------</div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="item-2"> <a href="#item-2">Payment</a>
                <div>
                    <p>Tab Content 2</p>
                     <div class="footer">---------</div>
                </div>                
            </li>
            <li id="item-3"> <a href="#item-3">Returns</a>
                <div id="notice">
                    <p>content </p>
                    <div class="footer">---------</div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="item-4" title="click for Tab 4"> <a href="#item-4">Tab 4</a>
                <div>
                    <p>Tab Content 4</p>
                    <div class="footer">------------</div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div></td>
```

CSS:

```
.css-tabs {
    position: relative;
    text-align: left; /* This is only if you want the tab items at the center */
    height: auto;
    margin-left:-30px;
    display: 
}
.css-tabs ul.noint11_menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block; /* Change this to block or inline for non-center alignment */
}
.css-tabs ul.noint11_menu > li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.css-tabs ul.noint11_menu li > a {
    color: #EEEEEE;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    font-family: 'MuliLight', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #002232;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #014464;

}
.css-tabs ul.noint11_menu li > div {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    color: #ccc;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 32px;
    background: #181818 /* added this */;
    height:350px

}
.css-tabs ul.noint11_menu li > div > p {
    border: transparent;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}
.css-tabs ul.noint11_menu li > a:focus {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.css-tabs ul.noint11_menu li:target > a {
    cursor: default;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.css-tabs ul.noint11_menu li:target > div {
    display: block;
}
#item-1 div {display: block}
#item-2 div { height:535px}
#item-3 div { height:535px}
#item-4 div { height:535px}



.footer{color:#fff; text-align:center}​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IE8 does not support `:target`](http://caniuse.com/#search=target), which is what you are relying on to show those tabs.

I believe your best alternative would be to separate the tab content into different pages, and use a set of links at the top for navigation. Your nav links can be styled to look like tabs, so the site can still look the same - you'd just have a page load after clicking each tab.

That alternative would also be less confusing even for users with modern browsers, since their back and forward buttons will behave in a predictable way while they're browsing the site.

`:target` is better used for highlighting which in-page anchor the user has jumped to after clicking a section link. Using it to fake a tab control where large chunks of primary content in the page are hidden does not seem very accessible or user friendly.

Comment: how can I replicate this listing. they are only using css: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/190741304903?item=190741304903&_trksid=p5197.m462

Comment: They are using JS for the tabs in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a CSS feature `:target` which is not supported in IE8.

If you want to support older browsers, the best solution would be to re-think your navigation design so that it doesn't use modern browser features that won't exist in those browsers.

However, if you do need to use this feature, you may get some help from the [Selectivizr library](http://selectivizr.com/). This is a polyfill script that adds support for a wide range of modern CSS selectors to old versions of IE.

This includes the `:target` selector, so in theory, adding Selectivizr to your site should solve your problem. (note however, that in the case of `:target`, Selectivizr only supports IE8; if you need to also support IE7 or IE6, it won't work -- even Selectivizr can only do much with what it's given).

(Also note that Selectivizr requires you to also include a supporting library such as jQuery; I note that your page currently doesn't have any javascript at all, so this might be quite a big burden to add, but you could at least minimise the impact by coding it using conditional comments so that it only gets loaded by IE8)